# Adding HTTP Headers in JSP

Tags: spring, http-headers

I am creating a Spring REST web services, that communicates with Android App and JSP web pages.

The method at my spring controller is like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView userLogin(@RequestBody User user,
            HttpServletRequest request){

         //do something with user


}
```

Andoid App is able to access this method through adding request Headres like 
"Content-Type" application/json , "Accept" application/json etc. Here the user information sent by android end is comes in **request body**. Thats ok..

But problem occurs when i POST the contents from my JSP page. I am not able to access the same **userLogin** method from jsp page with **@RequestBody** but when i replace it with **@ModelAttribute** it works for jsp page ...but then doesn't works for android app. Please tell me how can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the JSP page do the same thing as the android app (posting as JSON) using JavaScript, or implement a second method in your Spring controller (userLogin2), mapped to a different URL, and use this URL in your JSP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But i want the same method for jsp pages to use. Can you please tell how i can add HTTP headers with Javascript?

Comment: Look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/